# BigQuery: Return First Value from Different Groups in a Group By

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, standards

I am currently having a problem with a Standard SQL query. I have a list of emails where every email can have multiple functions. See the example below on how the table looks like.

```
Email                         Function
peter@gmail.com               engineer
peter@gmail.com               specialist
dave@gmail.com                analyst
dave@gmail.com                tester
dave@gmail.com                manager
michael@gmail.com             intern
```

What I want is a query that returns every email once with the first function it finds. So the above table should return the following:

```
Email                         Function
peter@gmail.com               engineer
dave@gmail.com                analyst
michael@gmail.com             intern
```

How do I do this?

What I have right now is a simplified version of the query.

```
SELECT Email, Function
FROM database
GROUP BY Email, Function
```

The issue is here is that I have to put both Email and Function in the GROUP BY. If I only put Email in the Group By the query cannot run even though I only want the query to GROUP BY Email.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no "first" in SQL, unless the order is specified.

Answer (score 12):

Use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by email order by funcion) as rn
from tablename
)a where rn=1
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as the "first" function, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets -- especially in a designed-from-the-ground-up parallel database such as BigQuery.

You need to use some sort of aggregation function.

A simple one is `any_value()`:

```
SELECT Email, ANY_VALUE(Function)
FROM database
GROUP BY Email;
```

If you have another column that specifies the ordering, then it can be used to fetch the `function` associated with the minimum value of that column.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered the BigQuery Navigation Functions?
For example, FIRST_VALUE.
You can view this in the documents [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=en_US&_ga=2.147999927.-1447139772.1563974816#first_value) and perhaps do something like the below:

```
SELECT Email, 
    FIRST_VALUE(Function)
        OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY x ) AS First_Function
FROM database
```

However, the other comments hint to the problem of ordering.

So you would need some sort of ordering variable (x), like a time, or even an index.

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()` analytic function

```
with cte as
(select * ,row_number() over(partition by email order by Function) rn
from table
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hacky way to get the first value when you need to use `Group By`

```html
SELECT
  Email,
  SPLIT(STRING_AGG(Function, ',' ORDER BY Function), ',')[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS Function
FROM database
GROUP BY Email
```

First, combine value from field `Function` into 1 separated by `,` and sorted by field `Function` using `STRING_AGG()` function.
Then get the first value using `SPLIT()[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)]`.

You can change `ORDER BY Function` with other fields (e.g. event timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

You need ordering column that specify your column ordering then you can do :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.pk = (select min(t1.pk) from table t1 where t1.email = t.email);
```

Here assuming `pk` is identity column.